# How to run jsoup code from maven in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsoup

I created a new maven project in Eclipse and created a file `Main.java` under `src/main/java/parser`. Here the package is `parser` in which my `Main.java` file is located. Here are the contents of `Main.java`, which is an example from Jsoup website.

```
package parser;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
        System.out.println(doc.title());
        Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
        for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {
            System.out.println(headline.attr("title") + "\n\t" + headline.absUrl("href"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `pom.xml` file:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>mdlparser</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now, how can I run this project? I right clicked `pom.xml` file and hit `Maven Build` which opened run configuration window. What am I supposed to type here? I tried typing `package` and `eclipse:eclipse`. In both cases, the console's output says that the build was successful, but the output from my program(System.out.println) is not being shown in the console. Also I tried running it as `simple java application` but in that case I get `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Note: I know that you usually use a logger instead of using sysout. But I am really confused as to how to run this simple hello world like program.

Comment: right click on your Main class and Run As java application?

Comment: Yeah I already tried that. I get NoClassDefFoundError as mentioned in the question. Do you want the full stacktrace?

Comment: update the project first by doing a right click on project and then Maven --> Update Project.

Comment: Yes I updated the project. After that I right clicked my project and hit Maven Build. It says build successful, but where is my output from wikipedia? Do I have to run it in a different way? Note that, this same Jsoup code works if I make an ordinary java project and add jsoup's jar manually without using maven.

Comment: Same problem here. A just simple program with System.out.println become to not show in console the output after add the JSoup dependency. @JackBary Did you solve this?

Comment: No I was unable to solve it. I moved on to using another library for parsing in python for my needs.